# How to remove all rows that have values above the 99th percentile for certain columns in pandas efficiently?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe

```
           a           b           c           d           e           f
0   0.025641    0.554686    0.988809    0.176905    0.050028    0.333333
1   0.027151    0.520914    0.985590    0.409572    0.163980    0.424242
2   0.028788    0.478810    0.970480    0.288557    0.095053    0.939394
3   0.018692    0.450573    0.985910    0.178048    0.118399    0.484848
4   0.023256    0.787253    0.865287    0.217591    0.205670    0.303030
```

And a list of columns

```
cols_list = ['a', 'd', 'f']
```

I want to filter out all rows which have have values above the 99th percentile for all of these columns.
I could do something like:

```
for col in cols_list:
      df[f'q_{col}'] = df[col].quantile([0.99]).values[0]

for col in cols_list:
     df = df[df[col] <= df[f'q_{col}']]
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the operator `le` to compare the dataframe with the quantiles, then use `all/any` to check for values along the rows:

```
valids = df[cols_list].le(df[cols_list].quantile(0.99)).all(1)

df[valids]
```

Output:

```
          a         b         c         d         e         f
0  0.025641  0.554686  0.988809  0.176905  0.050028  0.333333
3  0.018692  0.450573  0.985910  0.178048  0.118399  0.484848
4  0.023256  0.787253  0.865287  0.217591  0.205670  0.303030
```